# Create .txt file inPowesShell containing Version number for all files in folder

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon,

Although I've been programming in VBA for 20 years, I'm on Week 2 with PowerShell, so please be patient!

I want to use a PowerShell script to create a txt file containing details for all .dll files greater than 15000 bytes within the specfied folder thus:

```
$MySourceFolderName = "C:\PetesStuff\01 Backup"

$MyOutputFile = "C:\PSOutputA.txt"

get-childitem $MySourceFolderName -recurse |where-object {$_.length -gt 15000} | where-object {$_.extension -eq ".dll"} |
    sort-object -property Length -descending | Format-Table Name, Length -auto| Out-File -filepath  $MyOutputFile
```

So far, this works, but I also want to include the File version, which can't be accessed in the same way that Name and Length can.

Can anyone help me out, please?

Thanks in advance

Pete

Comment: FYI, if you filter your files in `get-childitem` (with `-filter *.dll` as a parameter), your pipeline will be shorter and thus faster. Filter as close to the source as possible, or within the source where possible (in this case, in `get-childitem`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, can do! What you want is Get-Command (I don't know why, but I do know it works). We can put it in a little impromptu hash table in the Format-Table command. Also, I'm going to move the second Where statement to a -filter so the provider filters that for you, and toss in some aliases because this is such a very long line.

```
GCI $MySourceFolderName -recurse -Filter "*.dll" | ?{$_.length -gt 15000} | sort -property Length -descending |
    FT Name, Length, @{l="File Version";e={(Get-Command $_.FullName).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion}} -auto| Out-File -filepath  $MyOutputFile
```

Comment: Thanks for this - the only I issue I have is that when I look at the text file created, it correctly includes a field header of "File Version", but the entry under this header for each line in the file is the text string "File:", rather than something that looks like "1.1.53.18". Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like I forgot a nested property. Added `.FileVersion` to it. There is also ProductVersion, which may be different, and you may need to play with it to get the desired results.

Comment: Absolutely bang on. Thank you VERY much! Have a good weekend.

Comment: You're quite welcome! If this answer has sufficiently resolved your question please take a moment to mark it as accepted to show future searchers that this is a resolution that they can apply to their needs as well.

Comment: Oh, any chance you could explain what the "e" as in "e={(Get-Command..." stands for, please?

Comment: Sure! That's short for Expression. It's a hashtable with 2 elements where `Label="String"` and `Expression={ScriptBlock}` You can also use Name, or n, in place of Label